# Tesseract iPhone : how to identify number of characters?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, tesseract

I am using tesseract for a new app I am trying to build . I have an issue and I need your help . Is there anyway that tesseract can recognize how many characters are in an image and then save each character to a variable ?

In my app , tesseract recognizes the text and stores it to a label.text .

Answer (score 0):

You can extract each single character from the rest,t Tesseract produces. Then you'll need a container holding these. You can't create new variables at runtime, though.

Comment: thank you for your answer . is there something that I can read to learn how to do that ? I dont know how to program tesseract to extract  each single character .